# Adjust css style according to wrap state without using javascript

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a responsive layout which has two div, one floats to left and  another floats to right.

**The design is:** when resizing screen and the two div overlap each other, i want the right div float to left and be the new line after the previous left div.

Currently I'm using media query to implement this design. 1000px is the screen size at which the right div is about to overlap the left div.

Current codes below:

```
.divLeft {
    float: left;
}

.divRight {
    float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .divLeft {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .divRight {
        float: left;
    }
}
```

**However,** the size **1000px is not always sure.** Sometimes the right div is larger and the size 1000px has to be decreased, 
**What I want is that when the right div overlap the left div, it moves to the next new line. No max-width like 1000px is relied on.** Is there any other method to implement is design? Better use css only without js.

Thank you for your time!

----------------------------------------update 18th June--------------------------------------------------

It seems my description is unclear, here's my page, and what I want is when the "right" meet the "left", the "right" change to a new line under the "left".
**I cannot use screen width as a condition.** Thank you all!

```css
.divLeft {
  float: left;
 }

.divLeft {
  float: right;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type='text/javascript' src='../resources/libs/jquery.js'></script> 
    <script type='text/javascript' src='../js/U.js'></script> 
    <title>CVOM Document - Chart Demo Overview</title>
    <link href="resources/demoStyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
       <div class="divLeft">Left</div>
       <div class="divRight">Right</div>
    </div>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you explicitly don't want to use javascript, then perhaps `javascript` isn't the best tag for this question?

Comment: Yep it's my fault. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you do something simpler like this?

```
.divLeft {
    float: left;
}

.divRight {
    float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .divLeft, .divRight {
        float: none;
    }
}
```

**Snippet:**

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI';}

.divLeft {
  float: left;
}

.divRight {
  float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .divLeft, .divRight {
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="divLeft">Left Div</div>
<div class="divRight">Right Div</div>
```

#### Preview:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks.
Yep, this css could implement my current design but it still rely on a max-width. My first problem is that the max-width is not certain. I want when the right div overlap left one, the right one move to next new line.

Comment: @SummerSun Can you show the live example?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Which tool are you using to show the output? Meaning  I want name of the software.

Comment: @VenkateshPanabaka The name of the software is [**Google Chrome**](https://google.com/chrome).

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will solve your problem . you don't need **js** to solve this issue.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .divLeft {
        float: none;
        display:block
    }

    .divRight {
        float: none;
        display:block;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `div`s are already `block` in `display`!

Comment: yes I know if there have any css with `display` property for all div or else that's why i've write here. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. Yep, this css could implement my current design but it still rely on a max-width. My first problem is that the max-width is not certain. I want when the right div overlap left one, the right one move to next new line.

Comment: can you paste your code sample to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).  @SummerSun

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .divLeft,.divRight {
      display:block;
      clear:both;
      float:none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Yep, this css could implement my current design but it still rely on a max-width. My first problem is that the max-width is not certain. I want when the right div overlap left one, the right one move to next new line.

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to be beside each other you actually need to float them *both* to the left. Enclose the content in another container so you can work with margin and padding without risking breaking the flow.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="first">Left</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="second">Right</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container { 
    float:left; 
    width: 50%;
}

.container > div {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    color: white;
}

.first { background-color: red }
.second { background-color: blue; }

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .container {
        clear:both;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hng7zow8/3/

Comment: Thanks. Yep, this css could implement my current design but it still rely on a max-width. My first problem is that the max-width is not certain. I want when the right div overlap left one, the right one move to next new line.